# WakeLock finalized while still held: MqttService.client.xxxxxxx

Tags: android, crash, mqtt, android-wake-lock, android-powermanager

I encountered a problem when using mqtt:
Create and connect in Service. After the device is connected to the network, the link is normal. At this time, the router connected to the device cannot access the Internet. From the log, it can be seen that mqtt performs heartbeat processing. When the connectionLost callback method is triggered, the PowerManager often appears. Related print information: WakeLock finalized while still held: MqttService.client.QWERTYUIOP1006, then the current application was stopped, without any crash information and related information similar to anr. Has anyone encountered this problem?

By the way,My application runs on an Android device and is powered by the power supply. The screen is always on. I don’t know if it will have any impact.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.